# Parsing html and server side codes

Tags: php, html

How knows how the browsers render the html and server side codes? does the browser render it line by line? or do the server side code first then the html? specially in php? And is there a way to force the browser to do the php code first, and then the html, or not?
Any help?

Comment: Server-side code runs on the **server**, not the browser.

Comment: Could be the reason why it is called server side code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Server-side code is never sent to the browser. The server executes the PHP code and sends the resulting HTML to the browser, which then parses it. It already does what you want.

Comment: when the page contains php code, I want the server to do the php code first. is it possible??

Comment: @OmarTaha Read my answer. **That is what it does.**